# Django logged in user in models.py or signal handler

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

Is there a way to access the request.user in either models.py or in a signal handler?

I'm using the m2m_changed signal and defining it in my models.py - I'd like to access the logged in user there.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you need this information for?  You have to pass this data to model layer in some way and proper solution depends on how the data is going to be used.

Comment: I'd like to use it in a notification i'm creating - ie. the 'actor' in this case is the logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming user making a change is not necessarily record owner or author.  This means model lookups are useless and you need to pass this data via signal.

Good way to do this is to create custom signal which has current user as one of attributes and emit it in view code when the data is being saved.

Comment: Actually - is there a way to extend m2m_changed - i really need the signal to be sent on post_add for m2m_changed but I want to have access to the request.user there

Comment: Nope, you cannot really modify existing signals unless you change every place in the code where it's emitted.  What you can do is assign request.user to some model attribute in view code then check for it in signal handler.  Remember that it won't be there if different view modifies the data or there's no view level at all (scripts, background tasks, etc).